# How do I make Div A's child overlap its sibling, Div B?

Tags: html, css, sass

**UPDATED FIDDLE**

I have a table that shows some content based on filter input and I, just recently, changed the select tag for a custom input that searches among the previous select possibilities (much like a datalist) and displays them in a dropdown list.

But unfortunately, the dropdown list that I manufactured with the input is not overlapping the table, making it too small (only showing 2 rows, when it should show a little more for aesthetic purposes).

The simplified fiddle below represents my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/ozmLfk7r/

In this fiddle, the "response" div should be above the entire "table" div, like the options in the select tag.

- I tried making the "response" div position fixed, but the X-scroll (which is needed in my real use case) misaligns it with the input tag.

What should I do in this case? (Javascript answers are welcome, but pure CSS or SASS/SCSS, if possible, are preferred!)

```css
.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.filter > .actualFilter {
  width: 150px;
}
.filter > .actualFilter > .response {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.table {
  border: 2px solid #666;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <input placeholder="type filter here" />
    <div class="response">
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
      <span>This doesn't overlap the table :(</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <select>
      <option>Click me</option>
      <option>This Overlaps the table!</option>
      <option>This Overlaps the table!</option>
      <option>This Overlaps the table!</option>
      <option>This Overlaps the table!</option>
      <option>This Overlaps the table!</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly your fiddle is supposed to demonstrate. Please give instructions, what we would have to type in where, to see what you are talking about.

Comment: @CBroe I updated the post and the fiddle, but basically: I want the "response" div to appear in front of everything, including the "table" div.

Answer (score 0):

```
.filter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.filter > .actualFilter {
  width: 150px;
}
.filter > .actualFilter > .response {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 100px;
}
.table {
  border: 2px solid #666;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table span {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 150px;
}


    <div class="filter">
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <input placeholder="type filter here" />
    <div class="response">
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <input placeholder="type filter here" />
    <div class="response">
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <input placeholder="type filter here" />
    <div class="response">
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <input placeholder="type filter here" />
    <div class="response">
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <input placeholder="type filter here" />
    <div class="response">
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actualFilter">
    <input placeholder="type filter here" />
    <div class="response">
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
      <span>Some Response</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
  <span>Some Content that doesn't matter in this case</span>
</div>
```

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/phpguest/pen/jObBMrE?editors=1100).